# what is the best way to get the Page URL inside Custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Inside my custom action filter how would i get the Page URL.

for example, if my url is:

```
mysite.com/Myfolder/MyArea/MyController/MyAction
```

I want to have a function that returns :

```
/MyArea/MyController/MyAction
```

Where **Myfolder** is the virtual directory in which my website is hosted.

Comment: By 'custom-attribute' you mean your custom action-filter?

Comment: is this how mvc route works mysite.com/Myfolder/MyArea/MyController/MyAction I thought default route is like controller/action/{paramifany}

Comment: @haim770...yes its custom action filter..i have edited the action.

Comment: You're gonna need to show your action-filter code

Comment: @qamar..i am using **areas** in my web app.

Comment: @haim770..inside action filter i am getting my page url and comparing the url with existing url's inside my database i.e i am making somewhat custom role based secuirty in my app.

Comment: @haim770..currently i am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` which is giving output as `/Myfolder/MyArea/MyController/MyAction` but i want `/MyArea/MyController/MyAction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string relativeAppUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

And if you need to remove the leading `~` (tilde):

```
string relativeAppUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath).Trim('~');
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it's working on localhost..i will test it on server and then i will accept this as answer...thanks for the help..!!!